# Scrolling indocator for Joomla one page site

Tags: css, joomla, menu, navigation

I have joomla website that is one page template. On the main page when user logs in for the very first time, it looks like there is no more content Downward.

I want to indicate on the top saying the message that "Please scroll down for more content".

Is there any way to indicate that msg is shown on top and when user scrolls down, it gets hidden????

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways of doing this, here's one possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/79mwymc5/

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll-down">Please scroll down for more content</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we hide message
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
                $('.scroll-down').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scroll-down').fadeOut();
            }
        });


    });

});
  }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Where should I put this code. I mean in which file of joomla. Should I post code???

Comment: @Programmer, for the message, copy the  HTML above, open your home page article, switch from WYSIWYG to code view and paste it near the top. For the javascript, depending on your Joomla article editor, you may be able to embed the JS directly into the home page article. It wouldn't matter too much where, though bottom of the page is best practice. Alternatively you could add it to your template javascript file. The specifics of exactly how you do this would depend on your template.